# User specified 'dlvLoadConfig' setting will be ignored by debug adapter 'dlv-dap'

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

When I launch in VSCode dlv debug, I get this message:

> User specified 'dlvLoadConfig' setting will be ignored by debug
> adapter 'dlv-dap'.

Source is Go Nightly extension.

have `dlvLoadConfig` config section already become unavailable (obsolete)?

launch.json :

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Application Server",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/main.go",
            "args": ["--config", "${workspaceFolder}/configuration/application.toml"],
            "env": {
                "CC":"/usr/bin/gcc",
                "GOOS":"linux",
                "GOARCH":"amd64",
                "CGO_ENABLED":1
            },

            "dlvLoadConfig": {
                "followPointers": true,
                "maxVariableRecurse": 1,
                "maxStringLen": 1024,
                "maxArrayValues": 64,
                "maxStructFields": -1
            },

            "trace": "log"
//            "buildFlags": "-tags dev -ldflags '-X main.BuildDate=2021-04-28T19:38:16+03:00'"
        }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to update your configuration as mentioned here:
https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#switching-to-legacy-debug-adapter

https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md
(from :https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/dlv-dap.md )

```
"go.delveConfig": {
    "debugAdapter": "legacy",
}
```

On a side note, installing the latest didn't seem to copy the binary as dlv-dap (which seems to be expected by vscode) I just created a sym link to dlv (mac-osx), and it works in dlv-dap mode

```
ln -s dlv dlv-dap
```

Comment: Thanks for link describe this issue. I'll try to use dlv-dap and get back to legacy when something go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Adding "debugAdapter" works for me too.

```
"debugAdapter": "legacy",
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#settings
The new dlv-dap takes a completely different approach in loading data, so dlvLoadConfig is no longer necessary.

For string values, it uses 512 or 4K depending on the context as of Aug 2021. (512 for display in the VARIABLES section, 1K for function call results, 4K if you query the variables from the DEBUG CONSOLE or use COPY VALUE)

I noticed you were using `maxStringLen: 1024` in your settings. We are currently considering to increase [the limit](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/513751573ea101f1d0f9373ed9b02fb716bfe566/service/dap/server.go#L179-182) of how much we show in the VARIABLES section. We are increasing this slowly and conservatively because it causes loading a lot of data for all variables automatically and it can slow down the debugging performance. If inspecting long string variables from DEBUG CONSOLE (on demand) is not sufficient, please open a new issue in the github.com/golang/vscode-go repo.

Comment: I used `maxStringLen` parameter to see complete text of variable. I saw while debugging in new version of VSCode improvement of watching variables. Example i can see maps correctly values with keys. Thanks. I got it, if I'll have some inconvenience in viewing variables i'll let you know. I think the good idea is to make possibility in watch window to cast variables to different types manually. And , of course, memory viewer always welcome.

Comment: Casting variables to different types should work already as long as casting is acceptable (e.g. string(b) where b is []byte). Please file an issue if it's not.